# Keycloak core deprecate class RSATokenVerifier, then, what is the replacement

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

Current, we are using Spring security with keycloak.

The code is as below:

```
...
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
OAuth2AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
String tokenValue = authenticationDetails.getTokenValue();
AccessToken token;
token = RSATokenVerifier.create(tokenValue).getToken();
userId = token.getSubject();
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDE, and it informs that class: org.keycloak.RSATokenVerifier is deprecated. I had searched and cannot find out any related information other than the documentation to inform that RSATokenVerifier is deprecated. If you know which class(es) to replace this RSATokenVerifier, please suggest me. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use org.keycloak.TokenVerifier class.

`AccessToken token = TokenVerifier.create(accessToken, AccessToken.class).getToken();
String sub  = token.getSubject();`

Comment: @ palak bajaj: Thank you for your feedback.